# Cannot explain what I thought was a mildly simple regex... (positive-lookahead - positive-lookbehind)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, positive-lookahead

Having a bit of trouble as to the result of the following regex, matching the following text.  I usually use regex101.com to give me a hand in quickly seeing output of regular expressions, but this time around Regex101 and Python are not agreeing on the same output.... and I cannot figure out why.

Sample text I'm parsing:

```
82% (37)\n31% (14)\n(missing = 8)\n76% (34)\n33% (15)\n(missing = 13)\n84% (38)\n53% (24)\n(missing = 7)\n18% (8)\n13% (6)\n(missing = 37)\n16% (7)\n13% (6)\n(missing = 39)
```

I'm just doing a split at (missing = \d(1,2}), while including the pattern.  So I've so far tried a couple different look-behinds, along with look-aheads.

Patterns tried:

1. `.+?(?=\= ..)`
2. `.+?(?<=\= ..)`
3. `(?=\d{2}\%).+?(?<=\= ..)`

As requested, link to what I'm currently trying:  https://regex101.com/r/JgaZ1n/1
https://regex101.com/r/JgaZ1n/2

reg=re.compile(r'.*?(missing = \d+)')
reg.findall('82% (37)\n31% (14)\n(missing = 8)\n76% (34)\n33%...etc...')

I expect a `re.findall()` to return first `82% (37)\n31% (14)\n(missing = 8)....` and so forth of others, but typically get either nothing, or just that what is contained within (missing `\d`).  Any insight a to why?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have to escape the parenthesis `\(missing = \d+\)` to match them literally https://regex101.com/r/22q0ps/1

Comment: You should provide a link to what you attempted at regex101 so that people can more quickly see your input and regex attempt without having to rebuild from scratch. Too often there is a mismatch between the SO post and what people actually try.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for the help.  That was definitely the issue in some of the expressions I desperately tried.    With your suggesiton and so forth, I've come to this pattern:     **.+?(?<=\(missing = ..)**   with returned result only being items inside (missing = )  º-º

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you got it!

Comment: @BoristheBarb If you match all the content and then split on it there will be nothing left to show. Can you add the code to the question so we can see what your intent is because you are also referring to re.findall?

Comment: @Thefourthbird just edited the question, I hope this helps =)

Comment: @BoristheBarb Do you mean like this? https://ideone.com/jLqrjq

Comment: Or to match every part like this https://ideone.com/MEXu5E